# SQLSyntaxErrorException: data type exception due to `COALESCE` in HSQLDB

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hsqldb

I had to upgrade the org.hsqldb library version from 2.2.9 to 2.4.0, in order to support schemas with `NOT EXIST` keyword as suggested in another question at this site, but then I encountered lots of JUnit tests which fails with

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException:                             
data type cast needed for parameter or null literal in statement
[INSERT INTO xxx(y) VALUES (COALESCE(?,?))]
```

my hsqldb looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE xxx (
    y VARCHAR (32) NOT NULL
)
```

they only thing that worked for me is to move the COALESCE logic to my Java sources before inserting.

**Questions:**

1. it makes me think that the requirement `NOT NULL` in the schema didn't worked until the version 2.4.0, and that's why my tests fails only now. beside deleting this requirement, there is anything I can do to avoid that restriction?
2. is there a function like COALESCE which insert default value if all the parameters are null?

Comment: *"they only thing that worked for me is to move the COALESCE logic to my Java sources before inserting"* What's wrong with that?

Comment: @Andreas I wondered if there is any other option to do so like downgrading to a specific version or change the sql query into something that can do the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it with a cast:

```
INSERT INTO xxx(y) VALUES (COALESCE(CAST(? AS VARCHAR(32)),?)
```